# How do I use Tkinter to create a ball everywhere my mouse clicks?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, mouse

I am trying to create a program that creates a ball every time the mouse clicks, wherever it clicks. I am new to Tkinter and its syntax, but it seems like a pretty useful GUI.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. This code also tracks whenever a key is pressed, and it prints the syntax for that key.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    pressedkey = repr(event.char)
    print "pressed", pressedkey

def callback(event):
    canvas.focus_set()
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y 
    ball = canvas.create_oval(event.x-15, event.y-15, event.x+15, event.y+15, outline='black', fill='gray40', tags=('ball'))

canvas = Canvas(root, width =1224,height=1024,bg='white')
canvas.bind("<Key>", key)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the [`Tkinter` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html?highlight=tkinter#Tkinter)